# Does Boomer ever drink from the toilet in Far Cry 5?

Tags: far-cry-5

Okay, bare with me here, but it's a stereotypical joke that dogs drink water from toilets. Normally, I wouldn't really concern myself, but, I'm becoming seriously curious at this point. Since freeing Boomer from the Peggies, we've visited three houses together. At each one, he somehow ended up in the bathroom, and, at the toilet of all places:

[image: Screenshot of Boomer facing a toilet.]

With this in mind though, he never actually puts his head in the toilet; he just simply looks at it. Since this is a running joke in a lot of media, I figured it *might* be one in Far Cry 5 too; especially after finding [a Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/farcry/comments/8cb5hz/til_boomer_plays_with_the_water_pump_once_you/) that shows Boomer playing in water after turning on a water pump. However, after searching the web for a while, I haven't found anything definitive on the topic; though this is likely because most players wouldn't normally concern themselves with it.

---

Is this just a huge coincidence, is it inferred behavior (as in, it will happen again but he never actually puts his head in the toilet), or does Boomer ever *actually* "drink" from the toilet in Far Cry 5?

Comment: "most players wouldn't normally concern themselves with it", probably neither the dog programmer

Comment: @pinckerman I presume the same lol but given that he plays in the water, I can’t help but wonder if there are additional little nuggets.

Comment: This would be the kinds of details you would find from Rockstar in Red Dead Redemption 2. But I highly doubt it is the case in FC5!

Comment: @Lesleyvdp I mean there are NPCs that urinate off of rocks, and I've seen Boomer urinate on a car tire, so I wouldn't be surprised, but I haven't seen it so far.

Answer (score 2):

No, Boomer does not drink from the toilet.

None of the animal companions (Fangs for Hire) have any form of environmental interaction at all beyond basic collision avoidance.

As far as the environment is concerned, they do not react to sound, light, moving objects or recognize specific locations or objects within locations.

Boomer can react to NPCs, vehicles, animals and hostile characters, but not scenery.

Comment: Can you cite an official source for this information (e.g. how do you know for sure)?

Comment: It's in the base code of the game.

Comment: Can you share that?

Comment: It's covered by copyright, and far too long to post here.

Comment: Copyright I can understand; but I *personaly* can't accept the answer without some form of official documentation to back up the claim. As a developer myself, I recognize that the code for games can be hundreds of thousands into the millions of lines of code. How can we be sure that the logic for handling specific environmental interactions wasn't missed?

Comment: In this case, you would look at the object instance for the toilet and simply check to see if it acts as a trigger for anything else. in this case the game doesn't distinguish between toilets and other environmental objects. it has no unique triggers or interactions.